# How to rotate and zip log file using size-rotating-file-handler in wildlfy?

Tags: logging, wildfly, logrotate, jboss-eap-7

We want to use size-rotating-file-handler available inside logging subsystem of wildfly for size based rotation and compression. But we are able to rotate the file but not able to do compression or zip . Is there any alternate in wildfly so that we can achieve log rotation as well as zipping simultaneously?

We have followed and tried below link but didn't get any luck:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278779

Note: We are using wildlfy-14 version.

We have used below CLI configuration for same:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:remove()
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/size-rotating-file-handler=FILE:add(name=FILE,autoflush=false,file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir,path=server.log},append=true,named-formatter=PATTERN,rotate-size=10m,max-backup-index=15,level=DEBUG)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.orm.deprecation:add(level=ERROR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add the `suffix=".zip"` attribute to your add command. However there is a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-4331) that prevented that from working which wasn't fixed until WildFly 16.

The workaround would be to use a `custom-handler` which I realize is not ideal, but would work.

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=FILE:add(module=org.jboss.logmanager, \
    class="org".jboss.logmanager.handlers.SizeRotatingFileHandler, \
    named-formatter=PATTERN, level=DEBUG, \
    properties={ \
        autoFlush=true, \
        append=true, \
        rotateSize=10485760, \
        maxBackupIndex=15, \
        fileName=${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log, \
        suffix=".zip" \
    })
```

The other option would be to upgrade to WildFly 16 :)

Comment: Hi James, thanks for quick response , as  of now will go for custom handler and soon will upgrade to wildfly-16 .

Comment: Hi James, the solution which you provide above it worked for server logs. Is there any way to do the same with wildfly access logs?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can set the [`use-server-log`](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/16.0/subsystem/undertow/server/host/setting/access-log/index.html#attr-use-server-log) to `true` which will write access logs through a normal logger.

Comment: Thanks James, will proceed with setting use-server-log to true as of now . One more query James in the above example **rotateSize=10485760** this is in MB or KB I mean what type it takes?

Comment: That is equivalent to 10 MB.